# What will happen if I have two htaccess/robots.txt files in two directories?

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, wordpress, robots.txt

I think there is (or I did something wrong) on my site: I installed a pre-made WordPress theme and normally they are installed as 'quick-install-package' with duplicator.

When I installed the package, I had no `.htaccess` and no `robots.txt` on the root directory. They were all in the => `backups-dup-lite` folder.

But while reading online and here, I found that they should be placed in the root path which is `public-html`.

The problem: when I Google `site: example.com` or any sub-page, I get only the homepage URL. I mean one link only. Website age is about one month and I have manually indexed it in Google and it says "URL already on Google".

That made me think I have done something wrong (because I have indexed more than one link and by searching `mysite: example.com` I should see more links, not one link. So I duplicated the files. Now, I have a `.htaccess` and `robots.txt` on the root, and also the same files on the duplicator folder. Hoping to solve the problem and see more links by searching my own site. Please keep in mind that I understand that it takes time to rank, I am just confused by seeing only one link despite indexing around 13 links manually.

I'm still not sure that I'm doing it right.

I'll appreciate if you share your experience with me and correct me on this so I make sure that I won't get in trouble later.

Comment: By "duplicator", are you referring to the Wordpress plugin?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I doubt that Duplicator would cause that specific problem.  Just and FYI, Duplicator has had several security problems over the years.  I would not suggest leaving any copies your database files behind after you duplicate your site.  https://wpscan.com/plugin/duplicator

Comment: Are you using g site: or mysite: (your question has both variants. When I tried using mysite: I got garbage results)

Comment: Note that the correct search term is `site:example.com` - there should be no _space_ between the `site:` search operator and the hostname and it is just `site:`, not `mysite:`, as pointed out above.

Comment: Does your site actually work? Can you navigate to all your pages? Do you get a 200 OK response for all your pages? Is your WordPress site installed in the "root" of your domain, or inside a subdirectory? Is the subdirectory part of the URL? What do your WordPress URLs look like, do they include `index.php` in the URL itself? Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` and `robots.txt` files in your question.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt **"The robots.txt file must be in the top-level directory of the host"** so the instance in the subdirectory will not be read and be of no affect.

Likewise, .htaccess files only apply to the directory they are in and their children - thus the .htaccess file in the subdirectory copy will have no effect on the main copy.